# db2 import and user access

Tags: db2, access-control

When I import data from DB2 using db2move, the dump file comes with the data exported as "USERX.MYTABLE".

The import process seems to be fine, I see lots of:

USERX.MYTABLE n rows imported ...

But USERX is not on my database and when I try to select data using MYUSER, I always get empty results.

Also, if I run db2move and export the data from my local database, it agains export all rows for USERX.

How can I fix the access to MYUSER?

Comment: See if this helps: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/58788/db2-users-beginer-questions/58789#58789

Comment: It explains why I see no data, but not how to fix the issue. I do not want to specify the scheme everytime I perform a query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to specify the schema explicitly, you can choose one of several options, for example:

- Modify the default schema in the session, e.g. by issuing the statement `SET CURRENT SCHEMA USERX`.
- Create an alias for the table USERX.MYTABLE in the schema MYUSER.
- Before importing data, edit the file `db2move.lst` and replace all occurrences of USERX with MYUSER.